# Multiples GET request

Tags: nodejs, api, axios, get

Estaria necesitando de su ayuda. Estoy haciendo un GET request a una API y con el JSON que me retorna extraigo un ID y lo paso a otra API para luego hacer otro GET y guardar ese response en un array para despues recorrerlo y volcar esa informacion en el DOM.

Uso NodeJS y Axios, el problema es que no estoy pudiendo guardar la informacion en dicho array, por lo tanto nunca llego a usarla en el DOM, cuando intento guardarla me retorna un array vacio. Pienso que me estoy complicando de mas y quizas sea algo mas sencillo de resolver pero hasta el momento no pude resolverlo.

Este es mi codigo:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
let gamesArr = [];
axios.get('https://platprices.com/api.php?key=<apikey>&sale=2601&region=tr')
    .then((response) => {
        gamesArr = response.data.game_discounts; //De este array extraigo un ID que lo paso a la api2
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    })
let openCriticId = [];
for (let i of gamesArr) {
        axios.get(`https://api.opencritic.com/api/game/${game.OpenCriticID}`)
            .then((response) => {
                openCriticId = [response.data.name, response.data.medianScore];
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            })     
}
console.log(openCriticId); //Este es el array que se retorna vacio
res.render('inicio', { gamesArr })
```

})

Otra forma de resolverlo que se me ocurrio es poder agregar cada iteracion del GET request de la api2 al JSON de la api1 y agregar solamente los key value que necesito pero no se por donde encararlo.

Saludos

Comment: ¿Para que haces la segunda petición si nunca la usas en el render ni en nada?

Comment: Al render le habia pasado el openCriticId pero como me di cuenta que me lo devolvia vacio gracias al ultimo console.log, lo saque y quedo asi

Comment: Prueba algo como esto https://pastebin.com/sACGDbgm

Comment: Hecho https://pastebin.com/77gsc0q6

Comment: ¿Hecho? Te pedía que pruebes el pastebin que te pasé en tu código, no que me pasaras tu código en un pastebin. ¿Funcionó?

Comment: Disculpa, entendi mal. En seguida lo pruebo

Comment: La primera vez que lo ejecute me dio error creo porque recibia un ID invalido -1, 0 o -2, inclui un condicional para que eso no pase y ahora veo que hay un error en el array de openCriticId, data no esta definida. openCriticId debe almacenar la informacion del response de la segunda peticion get. De la manera que esta ahora esta mapeado con el array games que es de la primera peticion.

Codigo con el condicional: https://pastebin.com/PzSpsCH4

Comment: Ok, vayamos por partes. Ya veo por lo menos la api que estás usando es https://api.opencritic.com/api y puedes adjuntarla a tu pregunta sin problemas, es una api abierta. En el pastebin que me mandas nunca cambiaste `api1.com/sale` así que es obvio el error. Por otro lado, no veo que los objetos que te devuelve https://api.opencritic.com/api/game/ tengan una propiedad llamada game_discounts. ¿Puedes adjuntar tus endpoints (url)? No creo que estés haciendo las peticiones correctas. Presiona EDITAR y cambia el nombre `api1.com` por el nombre real.

Comment: La api1.com la deje asi en el pastebin porque incluyo la api key en la url, ahora actualizo sin la key, respecto a game_discounts, es una propiedad que devuelve la api de platprices, de alli obtengo el OpenCriticID por cada juego que se encuentra en game_discounts

Comment: No se bien que tanta será la compatibilidad entre las api, pero bueno, de cualquier manera esto https://pastebin.com/zamvN8ww lo acabo de probar y funciona. Puedes basarte en eso para lo que quieres.

Comment: Ah! Y si revisas la documentación https://platprices.com/developers.php `game_discounts` NO trae `OpenCriticID`.

Comment: Voy a probar ahora mismo el ultimo pastebin que pasaste. La documentacion no esta actualizada, pero si trae el OpenCriticID.

Comment: Me devuelve bien el response, sale status 200 pero no puedo acceder a la data. Este es el primer item https://pastebin.com/rj1PNJeQ

Answer (score 0):

Yo utilizaría async y await

```
const getData = async (req, res) => {
    let {data} = await axios('https://platprices.com/api.php?key=<apikey>&sale=2601&region=tr')
            const gamesArr = data.game_discounts; 
            
        let openCriticId = [];
        for (let i of gamesArr) {
        const {data} = axios(`https://api.opencritic.com/api/game/${game.OpenCriticID}`)
          openCriticId = [...openCriticID, {data.name, data.medianScore}];
        }
        
        res.render('inicio', { gamesArr })
}
```

Comment: Me devuelve que gamesArr no es iterable

Comment: Tendrías que ver que es lo que te esta devolviendo la primera petición.

Manda una captura de lo que te devuelve la petición con un console.log

Comment: Me habia faltado reemplazar por mi api key por eso no iteraba, le tire un console.log e imprimio bien game_discounts. Ahora me devuelve que openCriticId no esta definida.

https://pastebin.com/00z8trmq

Comment: Bien entonces tendrías que ver que esta saliendo de la segunda consulta ahora,  sino trae esta propiedad openCriticId no lo puede asignar y por eso el error.

Comment: Me fije la segunda consulta y me dice que data esta undefined, no entiendo por que, le hice un console.log, solamente a data

Comment: Termine encarando la solucion por otro lado y pude, muchas gracias a todos